# add hard quotes to a list strings

Tags: php, string, scripting, string-formatting

Lets say I have a text file with a list of strings

like so:

```
434242019884
434244064888
434240746884
434241083881
```

Using PHP what is the most efficient way to echo them back wrapped with hard quotes (')?

I'm just curious.

Comment: "'" . "YouString" . "'" this is what you want???

Comment: actually this with single quotes around each number  ' ' . 'YouString' . ' '

Comment: are the string in the form of a variable, database field or user input?

Comment: Please define `most efficient`. Is that speed, less code, memory consumption? And how large is the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen("file.txt", "r");

  while(!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    echo "'".$line."'<br />";
  }

  fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: hmm so you open the file for reading only and while the file pointer is not at the end of the file get another line from the file pointer and add it into the $line variable concatenating a single quote on each loop then close the file -- it ALMOST works.. it is adding a double quote on only one side of each number.

Comment: or I guess it could be adding both single quotes at the end of each line instead of at the end and the beginning.

Comment: That is no double quote, it's probably two single quotes, I'll update.

Comment: This worked :<?php
  $fh = fopen("query.txt", "r");

  while(!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    echo " ' ".$line." ' " , "<br />";
  }

  fclose($fh);
?>

Comment: thanks bro -- that was super helpful. I really need to take the time to make flash cards of all the super useful built in functions in PHP. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
foreach($lines as $line){
    echo "'".$line."'<br />";
}
```

Comment: It's nice to see that `"'"` and echo is actually faster then `'\''` (and/or print) (Somehow, I'd expected `'\''` to be faster)

Comment: @PtPazuzu: Might be faster, just used it like that for readability.

Comment: I ran a quick test. It's in order of half-seconds per million lines, but still :)

Answer (score 1):

This will print your data properly, taking the newlines created by arrays into account.

1. Get the file contents. If there is more than one line of text in the file, it will create an array with each line as an item.

   ```
   $lines = file('datafile.txt', );
   ```
2. Start a loop that puts each array item in a variable.

   ```
   foreach($lines as $line)    {
   ```
3. Trim the new line from the end of the string. ( \x0A = \n )

   ```
   $line = trim($line, "\x0A" );
   ```
4. Echo the string, adding the newline where we want it.

   ```
   echo "'".$line."'\n";
   ```
5. End the loop.

   ```
   }
   ```

Here it is all at once:

```
$lines = file('datafile.txt', );             
foreach($lines as $line)    {
    $line = trim($line, "\x0A" );
    echo "'".$line."'\n";
}
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.....

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
echo "'" . str_replace(" ", "' '", $string) . "'";
```

EDIT: i did the code based on the spaces shown on your pre-edited message.. but you can change the space in the str_replace to an EOL

EDIT2: the $string is actually the whole list of strings, btw

Comment: Why not just `echo "'" . $string . "'"`? ...serious question since I'm a PHP beginner and don't see the need for over complicating issues (meaning I must be missing somethign).

Comment: see my edit2 :) $string is supposed to be the whole text, like "a b c", so the str_replace will replace the space with the quotes inside that string. echoing everyting at once instead of looping through each substring

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it using the explode/implode function in a single row:

```
<?php
  echo "'".implode("'<br/>'", explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("file.txt")))."'";
?>
```

This could not work in case your file lines are divided by "\n" (Linux style) instead of "\r\n" (Windows style), just fix changing the "\r\n" explode parameter with "\n".
This way you can control the first and the last hardquotes (in case you don't want the last <br/>) and you relay to library functions.
I just don't know how fast is this compared with other solutions.
Edit: made some tests, performs perfectly (maybe also faster than other solutions).